# defaultdict tuple of lists

Tags: python, defaultdict

I like defaultdict, but I want it to autovivify a 2-tuple of lists and I'm not sure if it's possible.  So what I want is:

```
foo = defaultdict(???)
foo['key1'][0].append('value')
foo['key1'][1].append('other value')
```

is this do-able with defaultdict?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. You need to give defaultdict a function that returns what you want the default to be; the easiest way to create such a one-off function is a lambda:

```
foo = defaultdict(lambda: ([], []))
foo['key1'][0].append('value')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
foo = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
foo['key1'][0].append('value')
foo['key1'][1].append('other value')
print foo
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f7b65b4f848>, {'key1': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['value'], 1: ['other value']})})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = defaultdict(lambda: ([], []))
```

Answer (score 2):

`defaultdict` of a `list` `2-tuple`? Just write the same thing, in python:

```
dd = defaultdict(lambda: ([], []))
```